# Android Phonegap HTML5 Audio tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, audio, cordova

Hello guys i hope you can help me with this problem...

I use Phonegap 3.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.4 ... Android 4.1.2

When I test the app in Firefox the audio player works perfect but when tested on the phone the player is visible but when I click on play nothing happens ...

Tried mp3 and ogg so it should support all browsers...

I saw lot lot of threads on StackOverflow ... even tried MediaElement.js as suggested ... but nothing seems to work ...
I know about the native media API ... but I really don't want to use it ... 
So I wonder if anyone has found a solution with this annoying problem ?

Thanks

Comment: if I use a .ogg file from a server it plays the sound ...  but it only plays once and then is imposible to replay ...

Comment: i'm currently searching for the same answer to this question. found out that chrome blocks autoplay on android and your app is essentially in-browser. don't know if this matters

Answer (score 0):

## Html

```
<audio id="play_audio" autoplay="autoplay" controls preload>
    <source src="your_audio_url" type="audio/mpeg" codecs="mp3"></source>
    <source src="your_audio_url" type="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.5 "></source>
    <source src="your_audio_url" type="audio/ogg" codecs="vorbis"></source>
</audio>
```

## Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play_audio").click(function(){
        $(this).load();
        $(this).play();
    })


})
```

Comment: yes I am ... Phonegap 3.1 ...  i found out the .ogg files from server works fine with a normal <audio> tag ... but when I try to replay ... nothing happens

Comment: try this directly 1)http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media both are working in my app

Comment: As i mentioned in my first post ... I cant use the media element but only HTML5 and JS